# .NET 4 WCF RESTful services deployed in IIS 6 is not accepting url contaning . (DOT)

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0, iis-6, wcf-rest

We have a WCF RESTful service developed in .NET 4 and hosted under IIS 6. It's working alright for all url's except the ones having . (dot) in url segment and giving error 404 - Page can not be found.

Example : http://services.abc.com/image/upload/**abc.jpg**/4/10

Image name has dot in them to specify the extension.

For development we have IIS 7 and it works perfectly fine on it.

Any settings we supposed to do in IIS 6 ?

Comment: Since we had to move ahead, i've used 2 segments one for image name and other for extension. http://services.abc.com/image/upload/imagename/jpg/4/10